# Open blender player minimized and maximize it when needed

Tags: 14.04, fullscreen, blender, minimize, maximized

I am trying to figure out how to speed up the starting of a game in Blender player.

The game is launched by a python script by popen. My question is whether it's possible to open it minimized when starting the python script and then maximize it just when needed.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.4 64 bit and I'm using Blender version 2.69.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `blenderplayer --help` you will find the following options

```
-w: display in a window
  --Optional parameters--
   w = window width
   h = window height
   l = window left coordinate
   t = window top coordinate

-f: start game in fullscreen mode
  --Optional parameters--
   fw = fullscreen mode pixel width    (use 0 to detect automatically)
   fh = fullscreen mode pixel height   (use 0 to detect automatically)
   fb = fullscreen mode bits per pixel (default unless set in the blend file: 32)
   ff = fullscreen mode frequency      (default unless set in the blend file: 60)
```

These options can be added as `Popen(['blenderplayer', '-f'])`

You can also switch fullscreen on/off from within the game by using [`bge.render.setFullScreen(enable)`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.render.html#bge.render.setFullScreen) within your game scripts.